# Why can't Pandas DataFrames contain lists as values?

Tags: python, pandas

I had a question regarding Pandas DataFrames themselves.

I've noticed that whenever I have a list inside a "cell" in a DataFrame, after I save that DataFrame using `df.to_csv` and call it back, that list is not a string object. If I want to use the list I usually use `ast.literal_eval`.

Why is it that Pandas DataFrames seemingly can't contain lists? Or perhaps I'm missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: "`list`" isn't a thing in `CSV` files. They are just text. You could try using [`to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) instead if you want to preserve lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is expected, because all data saved to `csv` are text.

If want preserve `list`s use another formats like `pickle` - write data by [`DataFrame.to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) and read by [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2], [3,5]]})

df.to_pickle('file.pkl')

df = pd.read_pickle('file.pkl')
print (df['a'].apply(type))
0    <class 'list'>
1    <class 'list'>
Name: a, dtype: object
```